# Symfony2 and Google API integration

Tags: google-api, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I am going to use Google API located on http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ with my Symfony2 application.

Is it possible to import this API with `composer` ?

What is the best practice to use this API with my application ?

Comment: The link is broken. Could you provide a link which should be equivalent to the previous one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably too late, but there is no need to use forked git repos, you can refer to Google's "native" svn directly.

Add the following section to your `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "project/google-api-php-client",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "source": {
                "type": "svn",
                "url": "http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn",
                "reference": "trunk"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Notes:

- `"project/google-api-php-client"` name there can be any of your choice
- If you need a particular revision, use "trunk@revision-number-here" format in "reference" entry

Then add the following line to your `"require"` section:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "project/google-api-php-client": "1.0.0"
}
```

That'll make composer to checkout the repo on the next update/install.

If you want Google API classes to be autoloaded, add the following line to your "autoload" section:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "classmap": ["vendor/project/google-api-php-client/src"]
}
```

It doesn't seem very neat to put the full path into the global "autoload" section, but I didn't manage to make it work with "autoload" section under `repository/package" yet :(

Comment: Added autloader settings details.

Comment: Well, I believe you must have svn installed in your system to grab packages from svn repository. 

From http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#git-alternatives _To get packages from these systems you need to have their respective clients installed._

Comment: To install it without any external tool you can specify a path to the archive, e.g. http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/files/google-api-php-client-0.6.0.tar.gz
Take a look at the example https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=187#c5 Also consider local classmap section

Answer (score 8):

Google have now started using github and have added a composer.json file.

Github: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient

```
"require": {
    ...
    "google/apiclient": "dev-master"
}
```

It's a shame there is no namespaces, but they are closer than before by having a composer file.

Comment: "Starting January 1st, 2015, the PHP Ads client library will stop supporting PHP 5.2".

Answer (score 1):

There is a Symfony2 bundle wrapping the [official Google API library **published by Google** on Github in 2014](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). That way, the API client is available as a service and you can store your configuration in the Symfony2 config file.

Symfony2 Bundle: https://github.com/Happyr/GoogleApiBundle

```sh
$ composer require happyr/google-api-bundle
```

```php
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new HappyR\Google\ApiBundle\HappyRGoogleApiBundle(),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There github repository for Google API https://github.com/evert/google-api-php-client with composer.

You can add to your composer.json file: "evert/google-api-php-client"

Comment: From the maintainer:  Important note
I've never completed this, and have no interest in further maintaining it. Please don't start anything new based on this. I'm keeping this repository around for the people who may still need it.

Comment: https://github.com/mybuilder/google-api-php-client/ seems to be an up to date version of it

Comment: This is the up-to-date repository published by Google: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client