# Symfony 2.3 Adding Google API

Tags: php, symfony

I used this before [Symfony2 and Google API integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521696/symfony2-and-google-api-integration)

I had a question about this, when I use the classmap in compser.json I am able to get to the Google_Client class, however I am unable to use any other classes.

For example I want to use the `Goole_YoutubeService`. I have...

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$youtube = new \Google_YoutubeService($client);
```

When I do this my code recognizes `Google_Client()`, but cannot find the `Google_YoutubeService()`.

Am I missing something to get this to work?

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": ["vendor/google/google-api-php-client/src","vendor/google/google-api-php-clien‌​t/src/contrib"]

},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "google/google-api-php-client": "1.0.0"

},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "phake/phake": "1.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
},
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "google/google-api-php-client",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "svn",
            "url": "http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn",
            "reference": "trunk"
        }
    }
}
]
}
```

Comment: Does `\contrib\Google_YoutubeService($client);` work?

Comment: Call to undefined function contrib\\Google_YoutubeService() No I get this error

Comment: See in the answer you linked to the part about autoloading? Try adding to the classmap like: `"classmap": ["vendor/project/google-api-php-client/src","vendor/project/google-api-php-client/src/contrib"]`

Comment: Add the folder for any other file you want access to from the repository: http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/

Comment: I'll take another try at that again, but I've posted my composer.json, maybe you can take a look to see if it has any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **Google_YouTubeService** - uppercase **YouTube** - it will work

Comment: Thanks! I realized that after I looked at the class mapping.