# Where to put the normal PHP library (ex Google API library) in symphony2 system?

Tags: symfony

I am making application with symfony2

I want to use Google API library in this application.

Google API has

```
src/config.php
   /Google_Client.php
   /and so on..
```

I need to load this script from the DefaultController.php.

Where should I put the library,and how could I load the library from the DefaultController?

If it doesnt have framework like symfony2.

it is very simple though..

put library in the same directory and load

```
require_once 'src/config.php'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply can run

```
php composer.phar install google/api-client
```

in your projectfolder. It should install the api-client to your vendors.

As you mentioned, default the config resists in another file. A proper way around that would be to create a little bundle with a nice config, register the api as a client, and pass the config to your service.

Comment: Thanks,I succeeded in installing api-client library.

Comment: However I have to change the setting in config.php.But this script is under vendor directory,I think I should not change files under vendor directory...How can I set the initial parameter without changing the file under vendor directory?

Comment: i updated my answer. since the config get passed in the constructor (https://github.com/Block8/Google-API/blob/master/src/Google_Client.php#L105) you could easily create a service and expose the config to your config.yml

Answer (score 1):

I think, since you are using Symfony2, the best way is to use composer and that would install the library inside the vendors directory and be added to the autoloader.

[Symfony2 and Google API integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521696/symfony2-and-google-api-integration)