# Symfony2.3, How to register a 3rd party bundle in Kernel, and load it from a Controller?

Tags: symfony, kernel, bundle, composer-php, google-api-client

I would like to get some help with symfony2 regarding the bundle registration in the Kernel,

Ive read most of symfony2 cookbook and doc for exemple : [How to install 3rd party Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html)

But yet everytime I failed doing so.
I am using symfony 2.3 with composer, both up to date.

Today I would like to use a 3rd party bundle called "google/apiclient"
found on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient), therefor i add the following line `"google/apiclient": "dev-master"` to my composer.json file which is located at the root of my project.

Followed by a `composer.phar update` in order to get the bundle which was downloaded with success and installed in the vendor repository

I belive that so far im doing okay, but the next step is where i get lost.

Next I belive ive to register this new bundle in the app\AppKernel.php
like the other one, for exemple:
 `new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle()`

But I don't know what to write for the `new google\apiclient ...`
**So first question is what should I write there and how do you figure it out ?**

Once this is done properly, I belive that i'm now able to use it in a controller,
but my second question is :
**How do i load the Client.php which is located in vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google ?**

The point of all of this, is to be able to sth like the given exemple in my controller:

```
 require_once 'Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'Google/Service/Books.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
  $client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");
  $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
  $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
  $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

  foreach ($results as $item) {
    echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
  }
```

The goal is to be able to use the google contact api in a symfony2 controller.
Any help or suggestion welcome, cheers

Comment: This library is not a bundle, you don't have to register it into your `AppKernel`. Also, it should be accessible just by calling `new Google_Client`. Composer does the job by [importing](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/composer.json#L13) the files you need.

Comment: If not, add it to `autoload.php` `$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Google'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google'));`

Comment: @Touki @waldek_c I see that composer has `autoload_classmap.php` where I can find my `'Google_Client' => $vendorDir . '/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php',` which is loaded from the autoload.php located in /vendor. But when i try to do  `$client = new Google_Client();` I get `FatalErrorException: Error: Class ... not found`, so something is still missing, i would like to add the line suggested by waldek_c but I don't know in which autoload.php im supposed to add this line ? Did i forget sth else ?

Comment: I followed the suggestions from  [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521696/symfony2-and-google-api-integration) adding `"classmap": ["vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google"]` in the composer.json file, but it still doesn't work

Comment: try `$client = new \Google_Client\Client()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people who like me couldn't figure out how to load a 3rd party library in a controller,

Here is what a did :

I wanted to use the google/apiclient found on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient)

1. I add the following line in `"google/apiclient": "dev-master"` under "require" to my `composer.json` file which is located at the root of my project.
2. Install the new library with composer ( in my case i used the command) 
    `php composer.phar update`

and it's done lol ... 
it's really that easy, the only thing left is to load it in your controller by calling the class directly.
For exemple in my case.
I wanted to `$client = new Google_Client();`,
 I thought I had to use `require_once 'Google/Client.php';` 
 but not at all if you used composer to install the library you can find that `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` return an array with the following line 
`'Google_Client' => $vendorDir . '/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php',`

So all I have to in my symfony controller is to :
**IMPORTANT**
`use Google_Client;`
and then `$client = new Google_Client();` and composer load it for me from its `autoload_classmap.php`
Or directly write `$client = new \Google_Client();`
I hope my experience will help some of you,
Cheers, and thanks to @Touki and @waldek_c .