# symfony 2.3 add third party library

Tags: symfony, autoloader

I'm trying to properly add FPDF to my Symfony 2.3.4 project as a third party library under the `vendor` directory. I was mainly following [this blog post](http://kiwwito.com/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2/). But I can't get it to work.

First of all, I'm not really sure what the vendor name and the library name is in this example. So let's say vendor is `OlivierPlathey` (the author of FPDF) and the library is `FPDF`, I'd create the wrapper class under `/vendor/olivierplathey/lib/FPDF/FPDF.php`, right? But what would the class name be? According to the blog post it should be `OlivierPlathey_FPDF`, but I think it has to be `OlivierPlathey_FPDF_FPDF`, because the library is called `FPDF` and the class inside that library is also called `FPDF`.

Secondly, there is no method `registerPrefixes`, because my project (for whatever reason) uses the `Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader` class, so I changed that to `$loader->add('OlivierPlathey_FPDF', __DIR__.'/../vendor/olivierplathey/lib/FPDF')`. Again, I have no idea what the correct prefix and path are. I think I tried all possible combinations I could think of, but none of them work.

I also tried adding a `composer.json` file, but nothing seems to have any effect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Is there some way to at least get an idea of where the class loader is looking??

Comment: you can find more detail steps 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857730/symfony2-3-how-to-register-a-3rd-party-bundle-in-kernel-and-load-it-from-a-con/27809318#27809318

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please dont do these kind of stuff, go on packagist and find the right package to install with composer command line interface. Class loader will be overwritten each time you'll use composer anyway,you shouldnt be touching it.

https://packagist.org/search/?q=FPDF

If you dont know how to use composer read its doc

https://getcomposer.org

Comment: So that means I just need to add `"itbz/fpdf": "dev-master"` to my project's `composer.json` and do a `php composer.phar update itbz/fpdf`?

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` Then it complains about `icu`: `symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library`. But why? I only want to install `fpdf`