# How to integrate the PHP client for the Google API with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have created a PHP application using `google-api-php-client`. I created a Google account email id from the Google console, I generated the *P12* file from there, and I put it into my local server. This works fine with "custom" PHP.

Now I would like to integrate the `google-api-php-client` library with my Symfony project in a custom bundle. I created a folder 'LIB' inside the `/app/Resources`, and I placed all files of `google-api-php-client` there.

Then I put the lines below inside the main controller to include the `autoload.php` file and to access the `Google_Client` class:

```
//require_once($this->container->getParameter( 'kernel.root_dir' ). '/../src/ABC/Bundle/TTBundle/Lib/src/Google/autoload.php');
$service_account_email = 'xxxxx-yyyyyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'API-Project.p12';

// Create and configure a new client object.
$client = new Google_Client();
```

but it shows me the following error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class
>   'ABC\Bundle\TTBundle\Controller\Google_Client' not found in
>   D:\wamp\www\TTPR\current\src\ABC\Bundle\TTBundle\Controller\WebAnalyticsController.php
>   line 133

Comment: You have to namespace it and to make symfony2 autoload that class

Comment: is it not possible to load that class inside the controller function?

Comment: Yes but you need to "instruct" (autoload) the framework

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you please write steps to make namespace and autoload , it would really helpful for beginners,
i created a folder 'LIB' inside the (current/app/Resources)
now i want to include file --> autoload.php inside this path:
require_once($this->container->getParameter( 'kernel.root_dir' ). '/../src/MWAN/Bundle/BIBundle/Lib/src/Google/autoload.php'

and want to use it in controller.

i would appreciate your help

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521696/symfony2-and-google-api-integration

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the problem by the following steps:

1- create a function inside my controller:

2-  inside the getService function , i called my self created function to include autoload.php file:

THE IMPORTANT THING NEED TO KNOW IS PUT A 'BACK SLASH' (/) WHEN CREATING OBJECT OF CLASS, I WAS MISSING THIS 'BACK SLASH' AND WASTED MY TIME, HOPE THIS WILL HELP SOME ONE AND SAVE TIME :)

```
protected function includeSsrsSdk()
    {
          require_once($this->container->getParameter( 'kernel.root_dir' ). '/../src/MWAN/Bundle/BIBundle/Lib/src/Google/autoload.php');

    }



public function getService()
    {


      $this->includeSsrsSdk();
      $service_account_email = 'xxyyzz@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
      $key_file_location = $this->container->getParameter( 'kernel.root_dir' ). '/../src/MWAN/Bundle/BIBundle/Lib/API-Project-xxxx.p12';

      // Create and configure a new client object.
      $client = new \Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName("HelloAnalytics");
      $analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);

      // Read the generated client_secrets.p12 key.
      $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
      $cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
          $service_account_email,
          array(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
          $key
      );
      $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
      if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
      }

      return $analytics;
    }
```